Bitlocker Encrypted drive C, not mounting and showing error, how to fix it?
So, my BitLocker encrypted drive C could be opened previously, but when I installed the wine package and removed it with autoremove wine; the problem started.
Now, when I try to open it, the following text is shown; Error mounting /dev/dm-0 at /media/lie/OS: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/bitlk-54977....(a huge string of character), missing code page or helper program, or other error'
Now, the thing is that when I try to open the file /dev/mapper/bitlk-54977.... with disk image mounter, it opens a new section with 'OS' written on it, and the drive opens but every time I boot I have to do the steps again to see the content in the drive.

This question is similar to: Linux Mint 22; Bitlocker Encrypted drive C, not mounting and showing error, how to fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)
